# I can't import some Libraries in main.ts(TypeScript) in Vue3.js project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, import, vuejs3

I needed to use country flags in my project ,so I decided to use the [`vue-country-flag-next`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-country-flag-next).

So I installed it and when I wanted to import it in my `main.ts` this happened :

[image: red error line appeared under my import line] 
 
so I hovered my mouse on it to see the error and the **error** was :
`Cannot find module 'vue-country-flag-next' or its corresponding type declarations.  ts(2307)`. 
I imported lots of libraries in my project and all of them was fine, and it's the first time I got this error, so I decided to use other `country flag` libraries and the error happened again, so I figure out something must be wrong with the file type(ts) and Searched about this but didn't find anything that can help me in this situation.

**What I've tried so far :**

1. Checked all the dependencies in `.json` files and in `node_modules` , everything was fine.
2. Try to fix it by adding `.vue` file in the end of the import line (someone in the internet says  that adding `.vue` can fix it , but it didn't )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is shown because the library does not provide a type declaration file. In order to get rid of the error, you have to create a type declaration file for it.
Follow the issue here, https://github.com/P3trur0/vue-country-flag/issues/72

Or you can just ignore it by commenting `// @ts-ignore` before the importing line, the component should work regardless.

```js
// @ts-ignore
import CountryFlag from 'vue-country-flag-next
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is generally because you are missing type declaration files (`.d.ts`) for your libraries. Either you create a file or you can install them  via npm.

1. Creating a `decs.d.ts` file manually in root of your project

```typescript
declare module "vue-country-flag-next"
```

2. Install them via npm

   `$ npm install @types/libName`
3. Suppress the warning

```typescript
// @ts-ignore
import CountryFlag from 'vue-country-flag-next'
```

**P.S:** I don't think there are type declarations already available for this library though. You'll have to check this. You can try installing [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-country-flag) library instead as it already has in-built type declarations.